# Proof of Function Equality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If we define $f,g: R \rightarrow R $ with the properties that:

1)$g(0)=0$

2) $2f(x)+f(1-y) + g(x) - g(y) = 3(x+1)^2 -6y$

How can we prove that $f=g$   ?

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $x=y$ we get

$$2f(x) +f(1-x) = 3x^2 +3 $$

substituting $x=1-y $ we get

$$2f(1-y ) +f(y)=3y^2 -6y +6$$

hence

$$3f(x) =6x^2 +6 -3x^2 +6x -6$$

thus $$f(x) =x^2 +2x$$

therefore

$$2x^2 +4x +3 +g(x) -g(0)= 3x^2 +6x +3 $$

hence

$$g(x) =x^2 +2x.$$